# Working with large csv and xml files

Tags: python

Hi I am quite new to python programming.

I have a very large XML file (300mb+) and CSV file.

I would like to map the data between the two files.

Currently I am using a nested for loops which takes a line from the csv and compared against all of the data within the XML and repeat.

However I realize that it takes very very long to complete, I am hoping to gain new ideas on how i can work around it thanks

```
with open(r"output.csv","w+") as outfile:  
    csvWriter = csv.writer(outfile)

    tree = etree.parse(r'input.xml')  
    root = tree.getroot()

    with open(r"input.csv",'rb') as csvfile:  
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)  
        for row in csvReader:  
        value1 = float(row[1].lstrip())  
            for child in root:
                value2 = child[1][1].text
```

Comment: add your code. what you have tried

Comment: What do you mean by "very large files"? You can always first load content of both files into list or dictionary and work on them - provided you have enough memory :)

Comment: I'm not an expert on complexity, but I think that if you have a CSV file with `n` rows and an XML file with `m` nodes, and you need to check each rows against each node, you'll get a time complexity of `O(n*m)` which may become a problem with large datasets. But unless you can prune the tree before or during the iteration, I don't think you can do much about that.

Comment: Can you add example data?

Comment: If you find it is expensive when your loop "takes a line from the csv and compared against all of the data within the XML", you might put the xml data into a hashed dict which your csv reading loop can inexpensively probe.

Comment: Your Code is incomplete, [Edit] your Question and show what you want to do with `value1` and `value2`?